# ERROR installing ftplib package on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, debian, ftplib

I want to install the `ftplib` package on Ubuntu, but I got the following error!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip3 install ftplib
**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ftplib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ftplib**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftplib is installed by default. You can immediately use `import ftplib` without installing anything.